# c#: to get the text from notes containing text and anchor tag using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have to find and replace text with another text in a string which consist of text and links in side anchor tag. For Eg:

```
abcdefg<a href='example.com' target='_blank' >example</a>pqrst<a href='some.htm'>some</a>cdefg
```

I want to replace the texts `abcdefg`, `pqrst` and `cdefg` with some other text.

Could you please help me to get a pattern for Regular Expression replace which replaces the the text like in the above example if exists. If `abcdefg` or `pqrst` or `cdefg` is not existing no replacement required.

Please help.

Comment: For HTML, the usual answer is to _not_ use Regular Expressions but [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: @UweKeim +1 This is the real answer

Comment: @Tinoy Uwe is trying to help you by steering you away from parsing HTML using Regular Expressions. This is because parsing HTML with Regular Expressions is bad practice, unreliable, potentially dangerous and generally wrong :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco I am working with a mobile browser safari for ipod. In that oage I need to take one string from database.This string consist of text and link .Firstly i added anchor tag to the links and applied to the string. Next i need to wrap the text other than the links since the safari doesnot supports break-word. Otherwise the word will overflow the page since the resolution of ipod safari is smaller.

Comment: What is the format of the string you get from the DB?

Comment: text format only.. for eg: Please visit the link: www.microsoft.com\n and please look here\nhttp://www.yahoo.com \nContact Us if you have some doublts.